# MariaDB 10.5.9 every day from 0:00 to 1:00 each 5 minutes shutdown

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos

Log looks like:

```
2021-04-29  0:00:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:05:02 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:10:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:15:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:20:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:25:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:30:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:35:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:40:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:45:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2021-04-29  0:50:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown

Apr 29 00:00:01 server1 systemd: Stopping MariaDB 10.5.9 database server...
Apr 29 00:00:02 server1 systemd: Stopped MariaDB 10.5.9 database server.
Apr 29 00:00:02 server1 systemd: Starting MariaDB 10.5.9 database server...
Apr 29 00:00:02 server1 mariadbd: 2021-04-29  0:00:02 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (mysqld 10.5.9-MariaDB-log) starting as process 19514 ...
Apr 29 00:00:02 server1 mariadbd: 2021-04-29  0:00:02 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384 (request: 32182)
Apr 29 00:00:02 server1 systemd: Started MariaDB 10.5.9 database server.
```

I disabled all crons and still shutdown.

My OS is Centos 7 updated.

I checked all logs and nowhere is nothing abnormal. From 0:50:02 to 23:59:59 mariadb works absolutelly perfect. I can not find what/who/why shutting down mariadb?

Answer (score 0):

"initiated by: unknown" is by a SIGTERM signal at that time. It will be in a script/timer somewhere that is running at a privileged or at the mysql user.

Given the 5 minute interval in that 1 hr window it does look like someone who can't write cron times correctly. Check the crontab for the mysql user.

Comment: in /var/spool/cron in not mysql/mariadb